# Each loop, stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby

My draft code for sin(x) maclaurin series:

```
def factorial(z)
  if z == 0
    1
  else
    z * factorial(z-1)
  end
end

puts "Enter x"
x = gets.chomp
puts "Enter n"
n = gets.chomp


(0..Integer(n)).each do |n|
k = ((-1)**(n-1))*(Integer(x)**(2*n-1))/factorial(2*n-1)
puts k
end
```

This code worked well until I added the `each` loop. Now I get `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)` error.

Without the `each` loop or `/factorial(2*n-1)` part everything worked fine. I cannot figure out what am I missing.

Comment: Why do you have `chomp`s? They do not make sense.

Comment: I want to read "X" and "N" user input.

Comment: Does it even work when `n = 2`? It could be that `2*n-1` is creating a rather large number, and Ruby does not have tail recursion optimization so you run into stack overflows a lot faster.

Comment: Why do you have `chomp`s? They do not make sense.

Comment: This problem is best solved using a loop, not recursion. Additionally, `n.to_i` is the standard way of converting values to numbers in Ruby. Using `Integer` is for exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
factorial(2*n-1)
```

For `n == 0` (first  iteration) this evaluates to `factorial(-1)`. You might want to change your factorial method to:

```
def factorial(z)
  if z <= 0
    1
  else
    z * factorial(z-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot about -1 scenario. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Just note, that other comments to this code hold. Using `Integer(n)` is not very ruby-like, use `n.to_i`. Ideal place for it would be **instead** of chomp.

Answer (score 0):

All `gets` values are strings.

You need to convert them in integer, like

```
puts "Enter x"
x = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Enter n"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
```

And in next code you should not to use `Integer(n)`, just simply use `n`.

Also want to note, that you should try implement factorial without recursive function. It could also to raise stack level exception for large `z`

Comment: Thank you for a tip. I have just started learning Ruby and I was wondering how to skip `Integer(n)` part.